# How do I get rid of RET being translated from <return>?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I'm overhauling all of my keybinds and I'm trying to keep it logically consistent.

When I issue the command `describe-key` -> <kbd>RET</kbd>

This pops up in the `*Help*` buffer:

```
RET (translated from <return>) runs the command newline (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.

It is bound to RET.

(newline &optional ARG INTERACTIVE)
```

What I don't like about this is the fact that <kbd>RET</kbd> is translated from <kbd>< return ></kbd>.

This is also the case with <kbd>DEL</kbd> -> <kbd>< backspace ></kbd>, <kbd>M-DEL</kbd> -> <kbd>< M-backspace ></kbd>, etc.

So to get rid of said indirections I issue the command:

`(define-key function-key-map (kbd "<return>") 'nil)`

And thus bind <kbd>RET</kbd> to `newline`:

`(define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'newline)`

But then I get this error in the minibuffer when pressing the <kbd>RET</kbd> key:

`<return> is undefined`

How do I get rid of this behavior?

I tried reading the documentation on map translations, but it is very confusing to me. Perhaps I haven't had that *AHA* moment.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want to get rid of such indirection? If a keymap you use (such as a minibuffer keymap, which you cite indirectly) creates such an indirection. Is this perhaps an [X Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: The reason I want to get rid of said indirections is twofold: 1) I want to eliminate every unnecessary layer of abstraction unless truly needed. 2) I want to keep my keybinds logically consistent; so instead of having keys bound to sporadic `DEL` and `<backspace>` arbitrarily, they will just be bound to `DEL`.

Comment: @Drew It looks to me that I'm gonna have to do some cons cell manipulation (correct me if I'm using that term wrong)? I'm looking at the variable `function-key-map` and I can see `(backspace . [127])` 127 is the ASCII code for DEL. Could be a clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For clarity: `"RET (translated from <return>)"` tells you that Emacs is *receiving* `<return>`.  That's what your OS sent it when you typed that key.  You *want* Emacs to translate `<return>` to `RET` for you, because the standard key bindings are for `RET`, not `<return>`.  Hence the error `"<return> is undefined"` after you removed that translation.

The reason for all this is that *terminals* send `RET` (which is ASCII code 13, aka `C-m` or `^M`), whereas in a windowing/GUI system the return/enter key has its own distinct code `<return>` (which terminals don't know about, and can't send).  Because Emacs supports both, it makes sense for the key bindings to be for `RET`.

Personally I recommend that you just leave things the way they are; but if you can't, then *maybe* something like this:

```el
(define-key special-event-map (kbd "<return>") 'my-ret-event)

(defun my-ret-event ()
  "Push RET onto `unread-command-events'."
  (interactive)
  (push '(t . ?\C-m) unread-command-events))
```

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Special Events`

Any key bindings which are *actually* using `<return>` then become inaccessible (that's probably an empty list, as such bindings wouldn't work in a terminal, but obviously it's still possible).

Experimentally, the various translation and decoding maps (although I didn't check every option) all seem cause Emacs to report the translation; but the special events are processed further behind the scenes.

n.b. I'm *not* convinced this is sensible, and for all I know it might cause problems in some situations.

Someone else may have a better method.

Comment: Great response and comment as well. I didn't know that it is actually the OS that sends `<return>` I spent a while trying to figure out where `<return>` was defined all for naught. But that now makes sense.